# Ошибка:"tuple index out of range" после запуска формулы

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

```
b = 'Буйносов И. П.', 'Иванов Р.О.', 'Маслова Г. А.'
c = ['^A{}^B{:.1}. {:.1}.'.format(*n.split()) for n in b]
```

После вывода на печать выводит ошибку "tuple index out of range". Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить данную ошибку?
Ожидаемый результат:

```
^AБуйносов^BИ. П.
^AИванов^BР. О.
^AМаслова^BГ. А.
```

Заранее благодарна за ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка вызвана отсутствием пробела между инициалами во втором ФИО - `split()` вернет две строки, а вы пытаетесь использовать три:

```
In [151]: 'Иванов Р.О.'.split()
Out[151]: ['Иванов', 'Р.О.']
```

добавив пробел после каждой точки, можно воспользоваться вашим решением:

```
In [153]: ['^A{}^B{:.1}. {:.1}.'.format(*n.replace('.', '. ').split()) for n in b]
Out[153]: ['^AБуйносов^BИ. П.', '^AИванов^BР. О.', '^AМаслова^BГ. А.']
```

или продолжить использовать регулярные выражения ;-)

```
In [149]: c = [re.sub(r'(\w+)\s+(\w)(?:\.\s*?|\w{1,})\s*?(\w)(?:\.|\w{1,})', r'^A\1^B\2. \3.', x) for x in a]

In [150]: c
Out[150]: ['^AБуйносов^BИ. П.', '^AИванов^BР. О.', '^AМаслова^BГ. А.']
```

---

```
In [158]: %paste
b = ['Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич', 'Овчинников Илья Игоревич', 'Телегин Максим Викторович']

## -- End pasted text --

In [159]: [re.sub(r'(\w+)\s+(\w)(?:\.\s*?|\w{1,})\s*?(\w)(?:\.|\w{1,})', r'^A\1^B\2. \3.', x) for x in b]
Out[159]: ['^AОвчинников^BИ. Г.', '^AОвчинников^BИ. И.', '^AТелегин^BМ. В.']
```

Comment: огромное Вам спасибо за ответы. В данном примере этот вариант хорошо сработал, но у меня есть авторы взятые из xml в таком виде: `['<lastname>Овчинников</lastname> <initials>Игорь Георгиевич</initials>', '<lastname>Овчинников</lastname> <initials>Илья Игоревич</initials>', '<lastname>Телегин</lastname> <initials>Максим Александрович</initials>', '<lastname>Хохлов</lastname> <initials>Сергей Викторович</initials>']`. Я перевела их в строку и тоже с помощью регулярных выражений удалила теги. Получилось: `['Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич', 'Овчинников Илья Игоревич', 'Телегин Макси и тд']`.

Comment: после этого я воспользовалась Вашей формулой и у меня все слова разбились на отдельные буквы. Вот так: `['[', "'", 'О', 'в', 'ч', 'и', 'н', 'н', 'и', 'к', 'о', 'в', ' ', 'И', 'г', 'о', 'р', 'ь', ' ', 'Г', 'е', 'о', 'р', 'г', 'и', 'е'`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я опять сделала не так???

Comment: @Ireen1985, хммм, не могу воспроизвести (добавил в ответ)...

Comment: у меня получилось!!! Спасибо большое!!!